# Form controls greyed out in Excel ribbon

Tags: excel-2016

I want to put a button on a page to run a macro but in the Developer section of the ribbon Insert in the Controls group is greyed out and can't access any of the form controls.

This is the only spreadsheet on which this is the case, Insert on all others is working fine!

What would be the cause of this?  How can I make form controls to work?

Reply   I have the same question (0)   

Comment: Did you copy and paste this from another forum? The line "Reply I have the same question (0)" seems to indicate that. If so, please post a link to the other forums where you asked the same question, so people don't waste their time trying to find a solution that has already been provided elsewhere. You're not making friends here for cross-posting.

Comment: I was advised in the other forum to do this, I am not really familiar with how these things work and did not intend to waste anyone's time.  This is link:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/developercontrolsinsert-greyed-out/420643ff-cb17-4d31-a46a-cd9315d1bff7

Comment: You were advised to post in a completely different forum, not here.

Comment: Which one is that?  I finished up on StackOverflow via one of the links.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the sheet is not protected. You cannot insert controls on a protected sheet.

Click the Review ribbon. If you see a command that says "Unprotect Sheet", click it. After that you will be able to insert controls.